# Storing count of table rows in a JS variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some old code I am trying to poke through. This table is loaded via a Controller action returning a model, based off of a button click somewhere else in the page.

How can I find the number of rows in the table in a JS variable? I am terrible with JS. I have tried a few things and nothing has worked. Below is my code and also what I have tried to do to store the num of rows.

Table:

```
<hr />
<div class="row" id="ReceiptsMainDiv">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow-y:scroll">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="terminalReceipts">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Terminal ID</th>
                    <th>Local Transaction Time</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Receipt</th>
                    <td class="hidden"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (var item in Model.TransactionsTests)
                {
                    <tr id="@String.Concat("rowIndex", Model.TransactionsTests.IndexOf(item))">
                        <td>@item.TerminalID</td>
                        <td>@item.TransactionTime</td>
                        <td>@item.Amount</td>
                        @*<td>@Html.ActionLink("View Receipt", "ViewReceipt", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" }) <br /></td>*@
                        <td class="transactionID hidden">@item.Id</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (item.ReceiptData == null)
                            {
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary viewReceipt" disabled>View Receipt</button>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary viewReceipt" data-rowindex="@String.Concat("rowIndex", Model.TransactionsTests.IndexOf(item))">View Receipt</button>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here is what I have tried to do in JS:

```
var rowId = "#" + $(this).data("rowindex");
    var row = $(rowId);

    console.log(rowId);
    console.log(row);
```

Results from the console.log don't appear to be accurate. Anything helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want the number of rows of your table.

```
// javascript
var rowsInTable = document.getElementById("terminalReceipts").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

//jquery
var rowsInTable2 = $("#customers").children('tbody').children('tr').length;

//if you need to do something with the rows:

var rows = $("#customers").children('tbody').children('tr');

rows.each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: I've not played with Razor in quite some time, but is there a way to access `Model.TransactionsTests.Count` and store that in a variable? Or perhaps add the count to a hidden element so you don't have to traverse the entire table

Comment: I'm not sure if this works but try Model.TransactionsTests.Count

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do that using jquery like this

```
var totalRowCount = $("#terminalReceipts tr").length;            //this will give +1 row
var rowCount = $("#terminalReceipts td").closest("tr").length;   //this will give actual row
```